# How to open a program/webbrowser without frames?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, video, browser, safari

I would like to open a browser window with no remaining content. I would like to see only the browser tab window without the menus and navigation bars. Is it possible? Is it possible to extract a video window?

[image: Example]

Comment: Open it in full screen mode?

Comment: no, must be open in window mode

Comment: What does: "*Is it possible to extract a video window?*" mean? Ignoring that part, this isn't a scriptwriting service but yeah that is probably possible. I don't do macintosh tho so ask a mac programmer.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to display the video in a separate window.

Sorry, i don't know technical english. I have attached a photo of what I would like it to look like

Comment: @HansRume did my reply help?

Answer (score 0):

For Google Chrome, you can use create a shortcut and add this at the end:

```
--new-window --app=https://google.com
```

This should open a window in "application mode" looking like this:
[image: Window]

So not exactly how you've shown on screenshot and not sure how it looks on Mac, but it's pretty close.